# BOTON DE EJECUTAR DESAPARECIO VSCODE

Tags: vscode, dart, programación-móvil, ejecutar

[image: En la imagen se indica donde debería estar el botón de ejecutar y como se me ejecutaba en consola de depuración en lugar de en la terminal cuando aún tenía el botón.]

Hola, estoy aprendiendo flutter y dart. Cuando ejecutaba un programa dart, me lo corría en consola de depuración y yo quería que lo ejecutara en la terminal, así que intenté corregirlo pero por accidente oculté el icono de "ejecutar" que se ubica donde indica la flecha roja. Es en VSCODE, ahora no sé como volver a hacer que aparezca, la única solución que se me ocurre es restableciendo vscode pero perdería todas las extensiones descargadas y configuraciones, alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Gracias!

Comment: Debes ir a los tres puntos que se encuentran en la esquina superior derecha y hacer click derecho sobre estos, después marcar la opción que dice "Run or Debug..." y debería reaparecer

Answer (score 0):

para que te aparezca ese icono debes descargar la extension code runner y ya; en caso de que no, debes dar click derecho en el boton que que abre ventanas en paralelo y activar el boton de run